# How to use dynamic linq groupby in method with IQueryable<T> parameter

Tags: c#, linq, telerik

Hi I have this existing code (now partially modified) where I have been tasked with replacing the dependency on telerik grid (the GridCommand parameter). Keen to avoid duplicating code, which I understand, colleagues have suggested adding my ListCommand as an optional parameter and modifying the preparelist method body to process grouping, ordering and filtering operations dependent on which instruction model is being used. I am trying to group results by multiple columns and am planning on using dynamic linq for doing this like so

`data.GroupBy("new(FirstName,GenderId)");`

It doesn't look as if grouping was fully implemented with the telerik grid parameter version but it is a requirement for it to be fully implemented now when using the listcommand parameter.

With the following code how would I be able to call the dynamic linq implementation of groupby which requires IQueryable not IQueryable in a way that fits with the logic and return types of the code shown?

```
    public JsonResult newRefreshList(
    ListCommand command,
    int actionId = 0,
    int objectId = 0,
    string parentObjectType = "",
    string relationshipFilter = "",
    ListParameters listParameters = null)
{
    return base.RefreshList<...
}

protected JsonResult RefreshList<T, TContext, THelper>(
    int actionId = 0,
    int objectId = 0,
    ...
{
    try
    {
        ...

        int count = 0;
        var list = LoaderBase<TContext, THelper>.BaseInstance.LoadList<T>(..., null, ref count, listCommand);
        var json = Json(new { Data = list, ...

        return json;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public virtual IEnumerable LoadList<T>(...)
where T : class
{
    ...
    return listl.GetList<T>(request, gridCommand, ref count, listCommand);
}

public virtual IEnumerable GetList<T>(..., GridCommand gridCommand, ref int count, ListCommand listCommand = null)
    where T : class
{
    try
    {
        using (DataContext) 
        {
            DataContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

            DbSet<T> dbSet = DataContext.Set<T>();
            IQueryable<T> qry;
            IQueryable<T> data = null;

            ...

            return PrepareList(gridCommand, data, ref count, listCommand);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to load the list of entities for type.", exception);
    }
}

public virtual IEnumerable PrepareList<T>(GridCommand gridCommand, IQueryable<T> data, ref int count, ListCommand listCommand = null)
    where T : class
{
    data = CrudHelper.SecurityHelp<T>(data);

    data = this.OrderQuery(data);


    if (gridCommand != null || listCommand != null)
    {
        data = (gridCommand!=null) ? data.ApplyFiltering(gridCommand.FilterDescriptors) : data.ApplyFiltering(listCommand.FilterCriteria);

        ...

        data = (gridCommand != null) ? data.ApplySorting(gridCommand.GroupDescriptors, gridCommand.SortDescriptors): data.ApplySorting(listCommand.SortCriteria);

        var sortedData = data.ToList();
        int page = (gridCommand != null) ? gridCommand.Page : listCommand.Page;
        int pageSize = (gridCommand != null) ? gridCommand.PageSize : listCommand.PageSize;
        sortedData = sortedData.AsEnumerable()
            .ApplyPaging(page, pageSize).ToList();

        return sortedData;
    }
    else
    {
        count = data.Count();
        data = data.ApplyPaging(0, 20);
    }

    return this ...;
}

public static class DynamicQueryable
    {
        ...

        public static IQueryable GroupBy(this IQueryable source, string keySelector, params object[] args)
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
            if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("keySelector");

            LambdaExpression keyLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(source.ElementType, null, keySelector, args);

            return source.Provider.CreateQuery(Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.GroupBy),
                new[] { source.ElementType, keyLambda.Body.Type },
                new[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote(keyLambda) }));
        }
```

Comment: My second reference to IQueryable above should have a generic T parameter which it looks as if has been stripped out on posting. hopefully everything makes sense.

Comment: `IQueryable<T>` derives from `IQueryable` so you should be able to call the method directly.

Comment: I think my problems are that calling directly inside the preparelist method complaints about implicit conversion between IQuery T and iQuery becaise i am trying to update the value of data with the result of groupby, i then dont know how to continue filtering and ordering which expect iqueryable t as input and i dont know if its apparent whether something is going ti blow up in the call stack back to the jsonresult if preparelist produces grouped results.

Answer (score 0):

> how would I be able to call the dynamic linq implementation of groupby which requires `IQueryable` not `IQueryable<T>`?

`IQueryable<T>` derives from `IQueryable` so you should be able to call this method directly:

```
public static IQueryable GroupBy(this IQueryable source, 
    string keySelector, params object[] args)
{...}
```

Question from your comment:

> I think my problems are that calling directly inside the preparelist
>   method complaints about implicit conversion between `IQueryable<T>` and
>   `IQueryable`

Yes it will complain because your `GroupBy` method returns `IQueryable` but you need to use it as `IQueryable<T>`. Therefore, you need to do this:

```
IQueryable<YourType> after = 
    query.GroupBy( "keySelector", new object[] { } ).Cast<YourType>();
```

Comment: The first part is ok, but the result of `IQueryable<T>` `GroupBy` is `IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, T>>`, therefore cannot be cast to `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: Yes thats what I had found which gave rise to the question about how to filter and sort with IQueryable<T> if i have IGrouping. I'll investigate more today

Comment: @Ian but wait, your GroupBy returns `IQueryable`. Am I misinterpreting your question?

Comment: It does but not an IQueryable<T> rather an IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey,TResult>> that syntax may be incorrect but the point is it produces igroupings not the flat list so any further processing needs to take acount of that. I havent got my code right now but will post what i came up with when i get chance.